# How to get all text copied from an array to a variable in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have an array which contains text data of a table, i want that data in the array to be copied to a single variable. how can i do that? can anyone help?
How can i modify this code so i get the data that is in arr copied to some other variable?
the code im using is:

```
$("td").each(function () {
        t = $(this).text();
        arr.push(t);
        }
```

Comment: `var new_arr = arr;`  doesnt work or am I missing the point here?

Comment: var foo = "";
    $("td").each(function () {
        foo += $(this).text() + ", ";
    }

?

Comment: it worked, but the point is im trying to print the contents in the array to a pdf, but the pdf is displaying a page, which has data cropped which exceded a single line, as some of the td of table has longer text that a line can accomodate in pdf page

Answer (score 1):

a bit simpler:

```
var all = $("td").text();
```

the `.text()` call concatenates the results

as per http://api.jquery.com/text/

"Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr = [];
$("td").each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).text());
})
//console.log(arr.join(' '))
```

Comment: `var arr = []` Added and you can get the `array` text using `join`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the width of the tag in which the data from the array is moving to( in the pdf).